# NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element:

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to type e-mail at the automation test using JS.

```
var driver = new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).build();
until = webdriver.until;

driver.get('http://www.automationpractice.com');
driver.manage().window().maximize();

driver.findElement(webdriver.By.linkText("Sign in")).click();
driver.sleep(10000);

var emailInput = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id("email_create"));
emailInput.sendKeys("natanatantsaq1w@pl.pl");
```

I get the error `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"*[id="email_create"]"}`
but I'm sure that this selector exists. Could you help?

Comment: Either the Id is not there in the HTML source, or it could be a timing issue, where the element appears on the page after page load.

Comment: Can you post some of the HTML on the page?

Comment: I would use wait and not sleep https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/until.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function you're invoking are asynchronous
You click and put your driver to sleep, but the rest of the code is still executed.

Try using the **await** keyword if you're in an async function, or **.then()** to execute the rest of the code

```
my_function = async () => {
    var driver = new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).build();
    until = webdriver.until;

    await driver.get('http://www.automationpractice.com');
    await driver.manage().window().maximize();

    await driver.findElement(webdriver.By.linkText("Sign in")).click();
    await driver.sleep(10000);

    await driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id("email_create")).sendKeys("natanatantsaq1w@pl.pl")
}
```

Check all the function you're calling to see if it returns a Promise

Comment: it worked! but i want to put it into function: and i did: 
    ```typeCorrectEmail() {
      driver.sleep(10000).then(function(success){
       driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id("email_create")).sendKeys("example@pl.pl");
    }});```  but i get the error: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: i tried it your way, but now nothing happens. I dont get any error, but it also doesnt start in my console when i type "node tests.js" (thats the name of my file)

Comment: I just tested it and it's working perfectly fine.
Do you call my_function() et the end? Do you have the correct version of the chromedriver?

Comment: In my exemple, you just need to call my_function() at the end of your script.

Comment: i forgot to call the function at the end :) now it works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The id is not matching to email input field,
try this,

```
var emailInput = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id("//input[@name='email']"));
emailInput.sendKeys("natanatantsaq1w@pl.pl");
```